# SFML Game Slows Down When Shooting Bullets

Tags: c++, sfml, bullet

I am making an asteroids game in C++ using SFML. I seem to have a problem though with shooting bullets. Although the class seems to work each time a bullet is shot the game significantly slows down. This is the code for the spaceship and the bullets. I just can't seem to find what's wrong with it! Thank you for your time.

This is the Code of the Ship:

```
#include "Spaceship.h"

Spaceship::Spaceship(void){}

Spaceship::~Spaceship(void){}

void Spaceship::LoadResources()
{

    if(!shipAnimImg.LoadFromFile("Resources/Images/SpaceshipAnimation.png"))
        std::cout <<"Could not locate the ship animation image" <<std::endl;

    if(!shipIdleImg.LoadFromFile("Resources/Images/SpaceshipIdle.png"))
        std::cout <<"Could not locate the ship idle image" <<std::endl;

    if(!bulletImg.LoadFromFile("Resources/Images/Bullet.png"))
        std::cout <<"Could not locate the bullet image" <<std::endl;

    shipSpr.SetImage(shipIdleImg);
    shipSpr.SetScale(0.5,0.5);
    shipSpr.SetCenter(shipIdleImg.GetWidth() / 2,shipIdleImg.GetHeight() / 2);

    x = DEFAULT_SCREENWIDTH / 2; 
    y = DEFAULT_SCREENHEIGHT / 2;

    shipSpr.SetPosition(x,y);
    shipSpr.SetRotation(90);

    std::cout<<shipSpr.GetCenter().x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<shipSpr.GetCenter().y<<std::endl;

    vx = 0.2;
    vy = 0.2;

    isBulletOnScreen = false;
    isPressed = false;
}

void Spaceship::UnloadResources(){}

void Spaceship::Update(sf::RenderWindow &Window,sf::Event event)
{

    if (Window.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::A))
    {
        shipSpr.Rotate(0.08);
    }

    if (Window.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::D))
    {
        shipSpr.Rotate(-0.08);
    }

    if (Window.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::W))
    {
        x += (cos(shipSpr.GetRotation() * (3.14159265/180.0)) *0.2);
        y -= (sin(shipSpr.GetRotation() * (3.14159265/180.0)) *0.2);
        shipSpr.SetPosition(x,y);
    }



    if (Window.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Space) && !isPressed)
    {   
    isBulletOnScreen = true;
    isPressed  = true;
    bullets.push_back(new Bullet(shipSpr.GetPosition().x,shipSpr.GetPosition().y,0.3,shipSpr.GetRotation(),bulletImg));
    }

    if (event.Type == sf::Event::KeyReleased)
    {
        isPressed  = false;
    }

    if(bullets.size() != 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<bullets.size(); i++)
        {
            bullets[i]->Update(Window,event);
            if ((bullets[i]->GetX() > DEFAULT_SCREENWIDTH + 40) || (bullets[i]->GetX() < 0 - 40) ||
                (bullets[i]->GetY() > DEFAULT_SCREENWIDTH + 40) || (bullets[i]->GetY() < 0 - 40))
                {
                    bullets.erase(bullets.begin() +i);
                }
        }
        std::cout<<bullets.size()<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<bullets.size()<<std::endl;

}

void Spaceship::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &Window)
{
    if(isBulletOnScreen)
    for (int i=0; i<bullets.size(); i++)
    {
        Bullet *cur = bullets[i];
        bullets[i]->Draw(Window);
        std::cout<<bullets.size()<<std::endl;
    }

    Window.Draw(shipSpr);
}
```

And this is for the Bullet:

```
#include "Bullet.h"

Bullet::Bullet(void){}

Bullet::Bullet(float x,float y,float v,float r,sf::Image image)
{
    LoadResources(x,y,v,r,image);
}

Bullet::~Bullet(void){}

void Bullet::LoadResources(float x,float y,float v,float r , sf::Image image)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->v = v;

    bulletImg = image;
    bulletSpr.SetImage(bulletImg);
    bulletSpr.SetScale(0.5,0.5);
    bulletSpr.SetCenter(bulletImg.GetWidth() / 2,bulletImg.GetHeight() / 2);
    bulletSpr.SetPosition(x,y);
    bulletSpr.SetRotation(r);
}

void Bullet::UnloadResources(){}

void Bullet::Update(sf::RenderWindow &Window,sf::Event event)
{
    x += (cos(bulletSpr.GetRotation() * (3.14159265/180.0)) *v);
    y -= (sin(bulletSpr.GetRotation() * (3.14159265/180.0)) *v);

    bulletSpr.SetPosition(x,y);
}

void Bullet::SetX(float x)
{
    this->x = x;
}

void Bullet::SetY(float y)
{
    this->y = y;
}

void Bullet::SetRotation(float r)
{
    rotation = r;
}

float Bullet::GetX()
{
    return x;
}

float Bullet::GetY()
{
    return y;
}

void Bullet::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &Window)
{
    Window.Draw(bulletSpr);
}
```

EDIT: Changed the code so that it loads the image inside the Spaceship Class and passes it to the Bullet's Resources after it is created. The problem still remains the same though. The game becomes more and more slower each time a bullet is shot and it remains slow until it is erased.

Comment: Does it slow down for the duration of the bullet or only at the moment it is fired?

Comment: It slows down while there are bullets on the screen. Even after changing the loadfromfile of the bullet to be loaded and passed in from the spaceship only once I still get the same slowdown. The program's speed is returned to normal when all the bullets are removed from the scene.

Answer (score 3):

**1.**
You are loading the `Bullet` PNG image from disk every time you create a new object (often, if you like shooting). The loading from disk is probably going to be very slow. Try to reuse the same image several times instead!

You could probably pull the `LoadFromFile` function out of `LoadResources`  and put it somewhere where it would last for the duration of the game. Then just have `LoadResources` refer to that place whenever a new bullet needs to be created. The same goes for any other images  or resources that can be reused in your game.

**2.**
I also saw that you have `std::cout` in your code. Try removing all of those that are in the rendering loop, as printing is slow.

```
for (int i=0; i<bullets.size(); i++)
{
    Bullet *cur = bullets[i];
    bullets[i]->Draw(Window);
    std::cout<<bullets.size()<<std::endl; // This is going to be slow
}
```

**3.**
You might also want to look at the `bullets` vector. When adding bullets to it,`push_back` changes the size of the vector, and that takes some allocation and deallocation of memory each time. A better approach would be to make room for a maximum number of bullets to start with (using the `resize` function for example) so that the vector doesn't change size whenever a bullet is created.

```
if (Window.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Space) && !isPressed)
{   
    isBulletOnScreen = true;
    isPressed  = true;
    bullets.push_back(new Bullet(...); // avoid this
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. Even after changing the png to be loaded only once in the spaceship class and passed in on creation of a bullet I still get the same slowdown while there are bullet objects in the scene.

Comment: Added to the answer. Try removing std::cout!

Comment: I have removed every console output I had but I still have the same problem. With every bullet I shoot it keeps getting more and more slower until the bullet is erased!

Comment: Too bad. I think the loading from disk and couts slowed it down significantly, but there must be an even larger bottleneck in there somewhere. I haven't used SFML myself, so I don't know how it does rendering etc.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call a new Bullet

```
Bullet::Bullet(float x,float y,float v,float r)
{
    LoadResources(x,y,v,r);
}
```

You also call `LoadResources(x,y,v,r)` which calls

```
bulletImg.LoadFromFile("Resources/Images/Bullet.png")
```

and that call read a file from a disk, which is a very slow operation, in order of magnitudes slower than anything else, so your program stops for the duration of the load.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question but even after I changed the bullet image to be loaded once in the spaceship class and passed it in the bullet when loading the resources I still come across the same slowdown while there are bullet objects in the scene.

Comment: @user2315574 You are calling code you didn't post so i cannot know what could be the problem. Maybe you spawn too many bullets at the same time.

Comment: I also agree with Armin. Just do a some debugging on the rest of the code and watch out where "Bullets" are unnecessarily/ accidently copied - maybe in some collision detection function?